# In node.js javascript why can't I add to a child function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
game_state = function(){
    this.players = function() {
        this.x = 0;
    };
}

game_state.players['test'] = 1;
```

Why does this fail but

```
game_state['test'] = 1;
```

does not?

I'm trying this in node.js in case it wasn't clear. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`game_state` is a (constructor) function.  Instances of the function have a players property, but the function itself does not.  I think you may want:

```
game_state = new (function()
             { 
               this.players = new (function()
                              {
                                this.x = 0;
                              })();
             })();
game_state.players['test'] = 1;
```

EDIT: The same applies to the inner function.  Also, in both cases, you can probably use object literals.

Comment: ahh... so obvious now ;)   Thank you